# find HTML input radiobutton from vb code behind, and if value is empty hide the radiobutton

Tags: code-behind, html-input, htmlcontrols

I need help finding HTLM input radiobutton from vb code behind onLoadpage, and if radiobutton value is empty I need to hide the radiobutton. I tried
         `

```
        For Each gvr As DataListItem In DataList1.Items
            Dim hf As HtmlInputRadioButton = gvr.FindControl("RadioButton1")

            If hf.Value = " " Then
                hf.Visible = False
            Else


            End If
        Next`
```

And I got an error msg: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControl.RadioButton' to string 'System.Web.UI.HTMLControl.HTMLINPUTRadioButton'
Thanks in advance